# How to move multiple files whith spaces in their names with python?

Tags: python, move, shutil

I want to move multiple files (only files not folders) from the directory `source` to directory `dest`.  I'm doing like below using a `for` loop:

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

source = "r'" + "/This is/the source path/"
dest = "r'" + "/This is/the destination path/"

files = glob.glob(source+'/*.*')    

for f in files:
    shutil.move(source+f, dest)

>> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

But if I do it for a single file like this, it works.

```
source = "/This is/the source path/"
dest = "/This is/the destination path/"

file_1 = r'This is a file.txt'
shutil.move(source+file_1, dest) ## This works
```

How can I dot for several files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portion of the path defined by `source` is going to be included in your file paths defined in `files`. Adding `source` to `f` in your loop would create redundancy. Instead try:

```
shutil.move(f, dest)
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are adding `"r'"`. Perhaps you mean to define source as raw input such as when you defined `file_1`? In that case you should execute something like this:

```
 source = r'/some/path/to/file.ext'
```

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. `shutil.move(f, dest)` is the correct way to do it. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

But how to print moved files name like if  I use print("Moved:" ) will be next argument in print statement

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32822434)